# Stacking Divs after screen resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to have two divs next to each other, picture on left, information on right, and I need them to stack (in the center) when screen size gets smaller.

Every time I try to fix it, the images stay floated to either side of the screen so they're not centered.

How can I accomplish this in either CSS or possibly JQuery?

```css
/* ------------------ team ------------------------------------*/

#team {
  background-color: #0370AD;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), #0370AD;
  min-height: 115vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#team #teamheader {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#team h2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#team p {
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
/* ------------------ profile divs ---------------------------*/

.profpics {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team_image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 550px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team_image img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team_info {
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.profpics h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
.profpics h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="team">
  <h1 id="teamheader">Our Team</h1>
  <!-- profile divs -->
  <div class="profpics">
    <div class="team_image">
      <img src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="team_info">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Executive Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profpics">
    <div class="team_image">
      <img src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="team_info">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Technology Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have a look a media queries

Comment: Show some screen shot, what exactly you are looking for!

Comment: Just a quick overview, you have set the width of ```.team_image``` and ```.team_info``` in px which will not work  if you want to make it responsive evrytime try to set the width of element in ```%```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a responsive design technique.  This means start with a mobile first layout with the profile pic above profile info, and then add a media query with a breakpoint, that changes your layout so profile pic is on left and profile info is on right of the same row.

The way that this is done is by using 100% width on your divs for the mobile small screen, and then changing div width and float with a media query at a higher screen size.  This is classic CSS responsive design technique.  I have created a cut-down working example for you.  It's not perfect, but it illustrates the technique.  The code shows the media query and how I have changed widths for higher screen sizes.  Note though, in general I prefer to use % widths for responsive design, but I have used px here for you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Profile Pics for Stackoverflow</title>

<style>

/* ------------------ team ------------------------------------*/

.clear { clear: both; } /* Apply style to a br and you can clear the columns of floating divs above */
                        /* clear both will clear both left and right floated elements above */


#team {
  background-color: #0370AD;  
  width: 100%;
  
}


/* ------------------ profile divs ---------------------------*/

.profpics {
  /* Column 1 is a container div over the other two columns */
  background-color: #99cc33;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.team_image {
  /* Column 2 left column */ 
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #D8AE1B;
  /* width: 550px; */
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.team_image img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.ImageIsResponsive {
       /*To centre image within div and make it responsive*/ 
    /*max-width means will expand to its full size but no more*/
    max-width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    /* To centre images within div column */
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.team_info {
  /* Column 3 right column */ 
  background-color: #B8292B;
  text-align: center;  
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

/* MEDIA QUERIES */  
/* for 768px screens or more */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.profpics {
 width: 900px;
}

.team_image {
  width: 430px;
}

.team_info {
width: 430px; 
}

}



</style>


</head>

<body>



<div id="team">


  <h1 id="teamheader">Our Team</h1>
  
  
  
  <!-- profile divs -->
  
  <div class="profpics"><!-- Column1 -->
  
    <div class="team_image">
      <img class="ImageIsResponsive" src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="team_info"><!-- Column2 -->
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Executive Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  
  <br class="clear">
  
  
  
  
  <div class="profpics">
  
    <div class="team_image">
         <img class="ImageIsResponsivesrc="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="team_info">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Technology Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
  
  <br class="clear">
  
  


</div> <!-- close team -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You!! Worked perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Hope this help you

```css
      /* ------------------ team ------------------------------------*/

#team {
  background-color: #0370AD;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), #0370AD;
  min-height: 115vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#team *{
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
#team #teamheader {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#team h2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#team p {
  color: white;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
/* ------------------ profile divs ---------------------------*/

.profpics {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding:100px 0;
}
.team_image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team_image img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.team_info {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.profpics h1 {
  font-family: Oswald;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 50px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid black;
  border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
.profpics h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
 .team_image, .team_info{
  width:100%
 }
 .team_image{
  margin-bottom:30px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="team">
  <h1 id="teamheader">Our Team</h1>
  <!-- profile divs -->
  <div class="profpics">
    <div class="team_image">
      <img src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="team_info">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Executive Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profpics">
    <div class="team_image">
      <img src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="team_info">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <h2>Chief Technology Officer</h2>
      <p>email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

have you considered using the Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)  framework? With bootstrap you can use the grid system to align your content easily for all views.

You could do this then for example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row profpics">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="team_image">
  <img src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="team_info">
  <h1>Name</h1>
  <h2>Chief Executive Officer</h2>
  <p>email</p>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
<div class="row profpics">
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="team_image">
  <img    src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="team_info">
  <h1>Name</h1>
  <h2>Chief Executive Officer</h2>
  <p>email</p>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- end row -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
```